# Java 8 iterate through list and store in Map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

```
List<String> list =new ArrayList<>();
list.add("abcd");
list.add("afsd");
list.add("addd");

Map<String, List<Person>> ordersByInstrumentId = findService.findAllUsers(**list.get(0)**)
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dummy::getId, Collectors.toList()))
```

My method findAllUsers takes a String as parameter. 
I want to replace list.get(0) with iteration, so it will call function for each element and store in Map. I tried list.foreach but it returns void so no use

Comment: What does `findService.findAllUsers` return?

Comment: `list.stream().map(e -> findService.findAllUsers(e)).flatMap(Collection::stream)`  would give you a `Stream<Person>`, maybe that's what you need

Comment: "I want to replace list.get(0) with integration" - what does this mean?

Comment: @berry120 I want to replace with iteration. My keyboard picked up the wrong Word.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you would need:

```
list.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> findService.findAllUsers(x).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dummy::getId, Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Thank you. I was iterating wrong with foreach. This is the good solution

Comment: @MarinescuRaluca cu placere ;)

Comment: `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dummy::getId, Collectors.toList()));` can be simplified to `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dummy::getId))`

Comment: @Aominè ah! Indeed